# ionic 4 native http get empty array

Tags: angular, http, ionic4

l am working on ionic 4 project. l am try to get data json array from url using  native http for ionic . When l try to get data array from url json l got empty page ! .

data json l have is too long , l put here short json to show scheme

```
{
  "result": {
    "airprotname": {
      "code": "BGW"
    },
    "response": {
      "airport": {
        "plugin: {
          "schedule": {
            "arrival": {
              "data": [
                {
                  "flight": {
                    "identification": {
                      "id": iaw445,
                      "row": 4861006050
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my code

```
  export class HomePage {

      public items : any[] ; 
      constructor(private http: HTTP) {



        this.http.get('/airport.json?code=BGW', {}, {})
        .then(res=> {

          this.items = JSON.parse(res.data.result.response.airport.plugin.schedule.arrival.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {



        });

      }



    }
```

html

```
<ion-content>

   {{status}}
   <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{item.flight.identification.id}}
      <div class="item-note" slot="end">
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

[doc for native http](http://http%20https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)

Comment: There is no `.number.default` properties in your JSON?

Comment: sorry , there was . but l have mistake when l copy the json . see my update

Comment: do you have any idea bro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse the intial response you get, before trying to access your nested data, so do...

```ts
this.http.get('/airport.json?code=BGW', {}, {})
  .then(res=> {
     const parsed = JSON.parse(res.data);
     this.items = parsed.result.response.airport.plugin.schedule.arrival.data;
  })
```